# Why 1 incorrect data is sent when sending data over TCP?

Tags: python, tcp

Every time when ı running send to data matlab from python, my one data is going wrong. what is wrong ? or how can i send data to matlab from python. I think my problem is input buffer but ı cant find the right solution. Thanks for help.

[This is wrong data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g8xkl.png)

> Python Code

```
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

s.bind(('127.0.0.1',9999))
s.listen(1)
print('waiting for connection...')
sock, addr = s.accept()
count = 0
datas=[]


while True:
   
    datas.append(random.random())  
    #datas.append(count)
    s=str(datas[count])

    sock.sendall(str(s).encode('utf-8'))
    data = sock.recv(1024)
    count = count + 1
    print('Received', repr(data))


sock.close()
```

> Matlab

```
t = tcpclient('127.0.0.1',9999);
all_signal_int = [];
all_signal_str= [];

count = 0;

while 1
    write(t,"---");
    while(1) % loop, until getting some data
        nBytes = get(t,'BytesAvailable');
        if nBytes > 0
            break;
        end
    end
    command_rev = read(t,nBytes); % read() will read binary as str
    data = str2num(char(command_rev)); % transform str into numerical matrix
    %data = char(command_rev); % transform str into numerical matrix

    all_signal_int = [all_signal_int;data]; 
    fprintf("%c \n",data);
    count = count + 1;
    %plot(all_signal_int,(all_signal_int+1000),'-r');
    %drawnow;
    
end
```

Comment: Please post as **TEXT**. See the **Code Blocks** section of the [formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). By posting text, it would be easier for people to copy-paste your code and run it in their environment.

Answer (score 0):

TCP is not message based, rather it is a continuous stream of data. So if you do 100 sends of 4 bytes each, you cannot know if the client will receive:

- 400 bytes on the first read, or
- 1 byte on the first read followed by 399 bytes on the second read, or
- 136 bytes on the first read, 17 bytes in the second read and 247 reads of 1 byte each.

Also, there's no need to UTF-encode data because sockets can handle binary data.

Combining these two ideas leads to a fairly generally accepted solution which is to:

- **pack** your floats into network-order IEEE754 4-byte floats before sending, and
- always read 4 bytes off the socket at a time (usually by receiving in
  a loop), and
- then unpack at the other end.

See `struct.pack()` in **Python** and `typecast` in **Matlab**.