# How can I get a Python socket object to read a continuous stream of raw TCP/IP data over ethernet connection?

Tags: python, arduino, ethernet, raw-ethernet

I used the Arduino Ethernet library WebServer example as a template to create a server on my W5500-EVB-Pico board. The data successfully shows up in raw terminals on the receiving PC, but the data cannot be read by a Python socket.

ON THE ARDUINO-ETHERNET SERVER END: I modified the loop() block to simply send some numbers as a sanity check, and I removed the http part (so it's just a raw stream of data):

```
void loop() {
  EthernetClient client = server.available();

  if(!client) {
    Serial.println("ERROR: no client");
    delay(5000);
  }
  
  if(client && client.connected() && client.available()) {
    Serial.println("*********new client*********");

    for(int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
      client.write(j * 6);
    }
  } else {
    Serial.println("failed to connect...");
  }
}
```

ON THE RECEIVING PC END: I wrote a simple Python script, and created a socket client to receive the data:

```
import socket

# Replace these values with the actual IP address and port of your server
server_ip = "140.102.1.33"
server_port = 5000

# Create a socket object
client_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

while True:
    client_socket.connect((server_ip, server_port))
    msg = client_socket.recv(1024)
    print(msg.decode())
```

I know with certainty that the data is getting to the receiving PC, because I could see it show up in both PuTTY and TeraTerm.

Comment: Have a read here https://stackoverflow.com/a/73149633/2836621